# Is there a way to use Page and Step objects between multiple projects with namespaces?

Tags: php, codeception

First and foremost, I'm using **Codeception 2.1 RC1**.

So, I'm bootstrapping multiple Codeception projects with namespaces as described here [Codeception Customization](https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/blob/master/docs/08-Customization.md)

Lets say I have two dirs **Frontend** and **Admin**, with suites (acceptance) respectively bootstraped with `Frontend` and `Admin` namespaces.

Is there a way to use **PageObjects** created in the Admin project inside the Frontend project?

The problem is, that when I try to instantiate a new Page or Step it requires me to pass the AcceptanceTester `object` (`$I`).

Example: 
I created a Cept test inside the Frontend folder and in that script I want to use methods from the Admin Pages/Steps. However, as there are two separate AcceptanceTester objects in separate namespaces I can't do that in the current structure of the framework. I tried including them as files too but they are dependent on other files (`classes`) and I'm guessing including them all isn't the right way to do it.

I suppose it can be done in some way by using the [new Autoloader](https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/pull/1228) or with more PHP knowledge than I have.

Any feedback and help is greatly appreciated.